# You passed a container to the second argument of root.render(...). You don't need to pass it again since you already passed it to create the root

Tags: setstate

[You passed a container to the second argument of root.render(...). You don't need to pass it again since you already passed it to create the root.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7q2z.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including specific information about any error or unexpected result you observe.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when i went to React 18 :

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root')
);
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
            <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The browser put an error.

You can remove it by deleting the last line in the root.render():

```
document.getElementById("root")
```